# WFP StmEdit not calling callout functions for inbound traffic

Tags: windows, driver, drivers, wfp, network-driver

I'm trying to get Microsoft's Windows Filtering Platform stmedit sample to work and am running into some difficulties.

When I turn on the InspectOutbound flag in the registry, set EditInline to 1, set InspectionPort to 80, set StringToFind to A and StringToReplace to B, and use a proxy, going to www.A.com redirects to www.B.com as expected since the destination is moved to part of the payload.

When I turn off the InspectOutbound flag in the registry (in order to inspect inbound packets), still using EditInline, still InspectionPort=80, accessing a simple http://www.somewebsite.com/somepage.html page I see that no functions from the driver source code have been called. I can see on WireShark that packets are in fact going through port 80 as expected.

I added a DbgPrint() call to every function in the source code to see the basic code flow without having to use the debugger for everything, although I do have it working and haven't been able to find the issue here.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Is this driver working for other people without modifications? If so can you help me understand why this is not the case here? If not what have others done to get this driver to work for inbound packets?

Why aren't the driver's callouts being called?

I suspect this has to do with the driver's filter, but documentation is lacking. I understand the filter has to be at the stream layer to be able to modify the payload, which it is here. I assume the fieldKey parameter is right but don't see documentation for it other than msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363996(VS.85).aspx